# jQuery click on menu and show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help for solving this jQuery problem. I have a menu made with bootstrap, I need to show a div when click in a menu item, and hide others. The divs are A B C, for menus A B C. They have to show in the empty white space.

[image]

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li id="a-btn" class="active"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-     dashboard"> </i>A</a></li>
  <li id="b-btn"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cd"> </i>B</a></li>
  <li id="c-btn"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"> </i>C</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="a-div"></div>
<div id="b-div"></div>
<div id="c-div"></div>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: yes ive tried all the day, .. that is why i can not solve this :/

Comment: You didn't seem to understand my comment. Show us what you have tried all day in order to swap those divs so we can help you fix what's broken. Cuz there are to many ways to solve this using jquery, vanila javascript, css-only and the power of boostraps data-toggle attribute

Comment: No problem, I solved the problem using this code made for me, it works, how I wanted.

Comment: Looks like someone have a helpful answer below, did you try it? Please respond to them, and consider upvoting or accepting their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this using my own code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#a-div').show();
$('#b-div').hide();
$('#c-div').hide();
$('#a-btn').click(function(){
$('#b-div').hide();
$('#c-div').hide();
$('#a-div').show();
});
$('#b-btn').click(function(){
$('#a-div').hide();
$('#c-div').hide();
$('#b-div').show();
});
$('#c-btn').click(function(){
$('#a-div').hide();
$('#b-div').hide();
$('#c-div').show();
});
});
```

Comment: It could've worked, but this isn't the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $("ul li").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
    
        $(".wrapper > div").removeClass("visible");
        $(".wrapper > div." + id).addClass("visible");
    });
});
```

```css
ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul li{
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:hover{
  color: blue;
}

.wrapper > div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
.wrapper > div.visible{
  display: block;
}
.wrapper > div.purple{
  background-color: purple;
}
.wrapper > div.green{
  background-color: green;
}
.wrapper > div.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="purple">A</li>
  <li id="green">B</li>
  <li id="blue">C</li>
</ul>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="purple visible"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```